# NullpointerException drawing Bitmap on Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Why do i get a NullpointerException?

Thank you!

ps:
I am new to Java.

```
    try {
        URL uri = new URL("http://static.panoramio.com/photos/original/41455707.jpg");
            URLConnection connection = uri.openConnection();
            Log.i(TAG, "connecting...");
            connection.connect();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8 * 1024);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();

            Log.i(TAG, "setting bitmap");
            //Log.d(TAG, canvas.toString());
            //Log.d(TAG, bmp.toString());
            canvas.setBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (Exception exc){
        Log.e(TAG, exc.toString());
        return;
    }
```

the output:

```
06-28 17:29:04.857   391   397 I MyWallpaperPainting: connecting...
06-28 17:29:07.248   391   397 I MyWallpaperPainting: setting bitmap
06-28 17:29:07.248   391   397 E MyWallpaperPainting: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: ok, i started with a new codebase and i still got that error, now i found out that if i use another url it works, so its the bitmap that is causing the problem! but why?

Answer (score 1):

This may be silly but did you initialize canvas somewhere previously?

Comment: i think so, at least `canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFF00);` works fine. this code is based on http://blog.androgames.net/58/android-live-wallpaper-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you did not initialize the canvas object.

Comment: i think so, at least `canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFF00);` works fine. this code is based on http://blog.androgames.net/58/android-live-wallpaper-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

is that one in the overriden onDraw (Canvas canvas) method?

Comment: no, the code is based on http://blog.androgames.net/58/android-live-wallpaper-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

InputStream is an abstract class, i dont think you can create an instance of it, have you tried:

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
new InputStream(connection.getInputStream()), 8 * 1024);

Comment: That would cause a compile error, no?  Instantiating an abstract class I mean.

Comment: I have had careless instantiations sneak past the compiler and cause null pointer exceptions as recently as last week

Comment: This isn't a template class we're talking about here.  The compiler knows that it's abstract.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good in game development, but why aren't you extending from SurfaceView and implementing Surface.CallBack and use inner AsyncTask class for handling threads? Does the job nicely! =]